# Tried to enter in root

Tags: xubuntu

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ su -
Password:
su: Authentication failure
```

I have given the password still it is showing the same as above, can any one help me out

Comment: @muru I don't think that this question is similar to that you have mentioned.  I'm not sure whether @user637289 is familiar with the difference between and `administrator`, `root` and `standard user` but he is tying a wrong method to enter as `root`. So his confusion was needed to be clarified.

Comment: @ManishKumarBisht you did see that the other user also tried su? And you read bodhi.zazen's answer, which links to the RootSudo article?

Answer (score 1):

`su` is used to authenticate as another user (if the account is there on the system; other than yours).
If you want to use `su` then you should use:

```
su username -c command
```

where **username** is the name of the account you are trying to use and **command** is what you want to execute.
It will ask you to enter the password. You will have to enter the password of the *username* account and not yours.

But since you're simply trying to enter as `root`, you should simply type:

```
sudo su
```

and enter the password of the `root` which is, by default, the password of your administrator account.
Here is a screeshot as an example:

[image: entering as <code>root</code>]

Answer (score 1):

To run the terminal as root,you should access root shell by superuser do `sudo`

There two ways to do that,

`sudo -i` where runs a shell with root privileges,and also acquires the root user's environment.

`sudo su`  where `su` is used to switch to another user, where you can also switch to the root user by invoking the command with no parameter. `su` asks you for the password of the user to switch, after typing the password you switched to the user's environment. Saying that `sudo su` command means your running `su` as `sudo`(root). calls bash as interactive non-login shell. So bash only executes `.bashrc`. You can see that after switching to root and you will still remain in the same director

Comment: That's why you should do `sudo su -` or `sudo -i`, so that you get a clean root environment